# Django can't find template dir?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Originally I had just one app in my Django project, the templates consisted of an index.html a detail.html and a layout.html ... the index and detail files extended the layout. They all lived in the same directory (*[app1]/templates/[app1]/*) and it could find all the files fine.

Now I've got a second app, and I want to re-use the layout.html ... I decided to make a templates dir off the base of the django project, and put it in there. Here's what my directory structure looks like now:

```
<basepath>/<django_project>/templates/shared
<basepath>/<django_project>/<app1>/templates/<app1>
<basepath>/<django_project>/<app2>/templates/<app2>
```

I updated my settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/full/path/to/<django_project>/<app1>/templates',
    '/full/path/to/<django_project>/<app2>/templates',
    '/full/path/to/<django_project>/templates',
)
```

In the 'shared' dir I have the layout.html ... from the app1 or app2 template dirs, I have the index.html and the 'extends' line at the top of the file reads:

```
{% extends "shared/layout.html" %}
```

However, when I try to load the apps view, it gets an error that it can't find shared/layout.html

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Caught TemplateDoesNotExist while rendering: shared/layout.html
```

Any ideas what I'm missing? This should be fairly straightforward, I must be overlooking something really obvious?

Comment: Might it be possible to show your TEMPLATE_LOADERS settings ?

Comment: Also note that if you have `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` enabled in your setting's `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` (which is the default), then you don't need to add mention of your "per-application" template dirs in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

Comment: From the error page, what does the section "Django tried loading these templates, in this order:" says?

Comment: NB! NEVER PUT YOUR APPLICATION DIRECTORIES IN YOUR TEMPLATE_DIRS SETTING. That's what the TEMPLATE_LOADERS are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad! I thought I was running this behind Nginx, so I restarted that and was still having the problems. After re-checking I realized I was running behind Apache, restarting Apache updated my TEMPLATE_DIRS and now it works!